# Fetching data from JsonRespone array

Tags: asp.net, json

```
{
        "contentServiceInfo": {
            "contentServiceId": 16199,
            "siteId": 9814,
            "containerInfo": {
                "containerName": "credits",
                "assetType": 2
            }
        },
```

The above code is Json respone from Server.I am using NewtonSoft for fetching the information.
Now I want to fetch the value of the containerName from Containerinfo object.
Can anyone provide me the solution.
I was trying the code below to fetch the details

```
foreach (JObject content in o.Children<JObject>())
            {
                foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
                    if (prop.Name == "containerName")
                    {
                        AccType = prop.Value.ToString();
                    }

                }                
            }
```

But still I am not able to fetch the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic object if you don't have a class.

```
string json = "{\"contentServiceInfo\":{\"contentServiceId\":16199,\"siteId\":9814,\"containerInfo\":{\"containerName\":\"credits\",\"assetType\":2}}}";   
 dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);                
var containerName = data.contentServiceInfo.containerInfo.containerName;
```

if json data is an array try following:

```
string json = "[{\"contentServiceInfo\":{\"contentServiceId\":16199,\"siteId\":9814,\"containerInfo\":{\"containerName\":\"credits\",\"assetType\":2}}}]";
dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var containerName = data[0].contentServiceInfo.containerInfo.containerName;
Console.WriteLine(containerName);
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception:'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'contentServiceInfo'. This is how I am converting the response and fetching the data: JArray o = JArray.Parse(json_siteResp);

Comment: what is your Newtonsoft.json package version? Mine:   <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />

Comment: 1.0 I have added the reference of netwonsoft

Comment: have you tried executing my code along with string json? Does your JSON data look different to the json string I used in my code? I don't see an array in your sample json.

Comment: Its an array returning from the web service to my browser.Yes I tried but got the exception

Comment: can you please post your sample array?

Comment: It worked you saved me.Can you please provide me your mail id for further help if might needed???

Comment: you can link me on linkedin.